# Echo toppers in a leaderboard using only 1 query

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql-server

I have used the below php code to retrieve the top 8 from an EmployeeTable (connection part I havenot included  below as it is irrelevant ) :

```html
$q4 = "select top 8 *
from EmployeeTable
order by LevelFieldTotal desc";

$stmt3=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q4);
if($stmt3==false)
{
echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
$toprow2=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt3);
```

I want to echo the top 8 in this leaderboard : https://jsfiddle.net/o20n61eu/4/

I tried to echo it in the html ,but I am getting only the ist person among the toppers getting echoed.

How Can I echo in the leaderboard,such that I get to see all the top 8 persons in the leaderboard through the above php variable,which holds the top8 in it.

***I donot want to do it individually for each person.I want to use the above query and fetch the top8 through only one query and echo it.***

the part of the html,where I tried to echo the php variable :(its in the above fiddele link also)

```html
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
  <div class="leaderboard">

    <ol>
      <li>
        <mark>
          <?php echo "". $toprow2[ 'EmployeeName'] . ""?>
        </mark>
        <small><?php echo "". $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] .""?></small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Brandon Barnes1</mark>
        <small>3101</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Raymond Knight1</mark>
        <small>2192</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Trevor McCormick1</mark>
        <small>2145</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
        <small>2103</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>And1rew Fox1</mark>
        <small>2103</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Tre1vor McCormick1</mark>
        <small>2145</small>
      </li>
      <li>
        <mark>Andrew Fox1</mark>
        <small>2103</small>
      </li>

    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

solution as suggested by @Magnus and @Mayank

```html
<div id="overalllb" class="leadboardcontent" style="display:none">
  <div class="leaderboard">

    <ol>
      <li>

        <mark>
          <?php while( $toprow2=s qlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) { echo $toprow2[ 'overallRank'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2[ 'EmployeeName'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2[ 'Total_points_Rewarded']. "<br/>";} ?>
        </mark>

      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help.Thanks.God bless.

Comment: If you check the manual for [`sqlsrv_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) you'll see an example. (hint: using a `while()`-loop). You're currently just fetching the first row from your result.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I got it.but if I do so,I will have to change the entire css. Also,If you look at the Javscript here,I am getting a popup as soon as I click an element in it.How do I change it to work if I use ur solution.I have mentioned your solution in the code above.Thanks a lot.God bless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```html
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
$stmt3=sqlsrv_query($conn,$q4);
```

here **$stmt3** is a sql resource type and you have to iterate it to get all data or use

> sqlsrv_fetch_array — Returns a row as an array

```
array sqlsrv_fetch_array ( resource $stmt [, int $fetchType [, int $row [, int $offset ]]] )
```

Returns the next available row of data as an associative array, a numeric array, or both (the default).

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mayank.but I am facing some issue with the javascript of the popup here.I have addressed the same issue above.Thanks,anyways.God bless

Comment: What kind of issue in JS popup?

Comment: @Mayank.What i have here is, if you look at the above fiddle,when you click on any employee name,you will see a popup with additional info.M facing issue here,trying to bring it up,when using your solution.thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ok, try it. And let me know if some help is required

Comment: Thanks.So kind of you to say so.

Comment: Congo, you are top 8% this week :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130102/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-jane).